# A little confused about the cons defined in scheme

Tags: scheme, eval, quote

the repl get answer :

```
> (cons 'quote '(a))
'a
```

here i think how it got the  right answer:

(cons 'quote '(a))  ---> (quote 'a)  ---> 'a

But i wonder why is not:

(cons 'quote '(a))  ---> (quote  a)  --->  a

the cons define is add the first arg into the first of second arg. the second arg is a list.

I also don't understand why it can't be explained like this :

```
>'(a)
(a)
>(quote (a)) 
(a)
>'quote
quote
```

why is not :
(cons 'quote '(a)) ---> (quote (a)) -- > (a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the result of `(cons 'quote '(a))` is `(quote a)` (the datum, not the code expression). Hence the result of `'a` is correct. To elaborate:

1. `(cons 'quote '(a))` conses together the datums `quote` and `(a)`, resulting in the datum `(quote . (a))`, which is the same as the datum `(quote a)` (that is, a list containing two symbols, `quote` and `a`).

   - Remember, for a list like `(foo bar baz)`, it's the same as `(foo . (bar baz))`, `(foo . (bar . (baz)))`, etc. So `(quote a)` is really the same as `(quote . (a))`.
2. Since `'a` is a reader shorthand for `(quote a)`, your implementation's writer chose to print it out as `'a` rather than `(quote a)`. But both are correct.

But in your post, you mentioned your expectation:

> (cons 'quote '(a)) ---> (quote a) ---> a

The first part of that is correct. `(cons 'quote '(a))` does evaluate to `(quote a)`. But now, that is a datum, not a code expression, so it won't get evaluated again. So it will not become `a` unless you explicitly called `eval` on it.

Comment: Seem like use drracket the different language show different.

Comment: [By default](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/printing.html), DrRacket displays results as an `eval`able datum, so for `(cons 'quote '(a))`, it'd print that as `''a`. The actual datum is still `'a`, but by printing it as `''a`, you can copy that into the REPL and get the result you expect.

Comment: USE lang R5RS in REPL , just print  a

Comment: That is not true. When I tested with `plt-r5rs`, it printed out as `(quote a)`. And with DrRacket in `#lang r5rs` mode, it printed out `(mcons 'quote (mcons 'a ()))`.

Comment: MIT Scheme: `(define xx (cons 'quote '(a))) ;Value: xx`, `xx ;Value 18: (quote a)`, `(map symbol? xx) ;Value 19: (#t #t)`, `(map symbol->string xx) ;Value 20: ("quote" "a")`. Using S-exprs as M-exprs has its drawbacks, makes you say "datum" a lot. :)

Comment: @yanxinyou You mean when you select "R5RS" from the dropdown menu in DrRacket the REPL behaves differently, like `(cons 'quote '(a)) ==> 'a`? Thats correct since it has different settings than the module language `#!r5rs` (== `#lang r5rs`).

Comment: @Sylwester.  Since #!racket  (quote a) --> 'a , #!r5rs  (quote   a)  --> a .  So seem r5rs eval the arg.  #!racket (eval '(quote a)) ---> 'a . while #r5rs (eval '(quote a)) ----> with eval args number wrong . So #r5rs was implement by racket , or exp was pass to racket lang . And this pass will eval the arg as arg in racket . I need to look racket docement .As i am studying The Litter  Schemer , Any suggestion?

Comment: @yanxinyou It's just presentation.. like you can write 17 as 0x11. You eval 'a. If you get just a, then it's displayed as data. If it's 'a you should ignore the quote since it's the racket evalable datum. Both work just fine when you know.